# How can I get a combined row of data from several rows?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Clickhouse data comes from different sources and ends up in one table. Each data may contain both complete and incomplete data.I'm doing this because I can't use Update, because I can't record the full set of fields.
As a result, the table contains several rows united by one phone number.
SELECT * FROM Customer;

```
| Phone     | Email          | Name     | City           |
| ----------| ---------------| -------- | -------------- |
| 998307900 | test@gmail.com |          |                |
| 998307900 |                |          | Tashkent       |
| 998307900 |                | Stefany  |                |
| 998307900 |                | Stef     |                |
```

How to write a query to get a string like this? This is a simplified version; in reality there are many more fields.

```
| Phone     | Email          | Name     | City           |
| ----------| ---------------| -------- | -------------- |
| 998307900 | test@gmail.com | Stefany  | Tashkent       |
```

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting Stefany over Stef? do you have a version number atleast or a timestamp maybe?

Comment: @gingerwizard Above is a more recent entry. The full name is because it came later. I can add a timestamp.

Comment: Yeh hueristics to detect its the fullname  will be costly. add a timestamp to each row insert if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with the first Non Null value for each column, you can use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example
(
    `phone` Int64,
    `email` Nullable(String),
    `name` Nullable(String),
    `city` Nullable(String)
)
ENGINE = Memory

INSERT INTO example VALUES (998307900, 'test@gmail.com', Null, Null), (998307900, Null, Null, 'Tashkent'), (998307900, Null, 'Stefany', Null), (998307900, Null, 'Stef', Null)


SELECT
    phone,
    any(email) AS email,
    any(name) AS name,
    any(city) AS city
FROM example
GROUP BY phone

┌─────phone─┬─email──────────┬─name────┬─city─────┐
│ 998307900 │ test@gmail.com │ Stefany │ Tashkent │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```

Ideally you'd have a timestamp or version to distinguish between non null values. In this case, you can use argMax (this skips Nulls also)

Comment: Ideally, if the data comes empty, then this should erase the data in the cell, but if the data comes as NULL, then we do not erase, but use the last value of the cell. I can add a timestamp and use empty and null - will this improve my code?

Comment: In which case use argmax instead of any, should do the trick for you. This will recognize empty values as valid but ignore the Nulls

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I'll try to make a Demo for testing and write what I did, but it seems to me that this is a good option.

Comment: AggregatingMergeTree or ReplacingMergeTree - Type?

Comment: Those will require complete entries be inserted i.e. current known state for each row, as merging will be per row. However, if viable then yes!

Comment: I did everything according to your example and added the Version and argMax. This is exactly what I wanted. I am very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that you used 'Stephany' and not 'Steph', so the last row entered.

A clickstream usually gets a timestamp when the entry was logged, and I assumed you have that somewhere. In SQL, I don't like leaving to chance how a result set is ordered, so I need an ordering criterion in my data - I call it `ts`, for timestamp, and add it to your data:

| ts | Phone | Email | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-06 08:00:00 | 998307900 | test@gmail.com | - | - |
| 2024-03-06 09:00:00 | 998307900 | - | - | Tashkent |
| 2024-03-06 10:00:00 | 998307900 | - | Stefany | - |
| 2024-03-06 11:00:00 | 998307900 | - | Stef | - |

Then, I use the LAST_VALUE, but ordering by the timestamp descending, function, to get the first, in time, non-null result for all columns you have (the only rule I could deduct from your data snippet and the result expected), and I use ROW_NUMBER(), ordered ascending, to get the ordinal number, and finally filter by row number = 1.

```
WITH
-- your input data enriched by timestamp
indata(ts,Phone,Email,Name,City) AS (
          SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 08:00:00',998307900,'test@gmail.com',NULL     ,NULL
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 09:00:00',998307900,            NULL,NULL     ,'Tashkent'
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 10:00:00',998307900,            NULL,'Stefany',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-03-06 11:00:00',998307900,            NULL,'Stef'   ,NULL
)
-- end of in data, real query starts here
-- replace following comma with "WITH"
,
filled_row AS (
  SELECT
    phone
  , ts
  , ROW_NUMBER()                   OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY ts ASC ) AS rn
  , LAST_VALUE(Phone IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY ts DESC) AS Phone
  , LAST_VALUE(Email IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY ts DESC) AS Email
  , LAST_VALUE(Name  IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY ts DESC) AS Name 
  , LAST_VALUE(City  IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY phone ORDER BY ts DESC) AS City 
  FROM indata
)
SELECT * FROM filled_row WHERE rn = 1;
```

| phone | ts | rn | Phone | Email | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 998307900 | 2024-03-06 08:00:00 | 1 | 998307900 | test@gmail.com | Stefany | Tashkent |